# Data source automatic binding

Tags: java, jdbc, websphere, jython, wsadmin

I have a JDBC datasource defined in WebSphere named 'jdbc/dataSource1'.
In my application based on Spring i want to obtain the datasource using jndi lookup, but by another name, like 'jdbc/dataSource2'.
To achieve this i created ibm-web-bnd.xml file, in which i defined the linkage as follows:

```
<resource-ref binding-name="jdbc/dataSource2" name="jdbc/dataSource1"/>
```

Also i defined the datasource in the web.xml file as follows:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>some awesome datasource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/dataSource2</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

The solution works only while deploying using IBM Web Console. When i try to deploy it using custom jython script using wsadmin tool, i get the following error:

```
ADMA0007E: A Validation error occurred in task Mapping resource references to re
sources. The Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) name is not specified f
or reference binding jdbc/dataSource2 in module <application_name>.war"
```

In wsadmin script i use AdminApp.install(path_to_ear, options), where options variable contain only options regarding virtual hosts mapping.

So the question is what should i do, so the WebSphere will get the datasource mapping options from ibm-web-bnd.xml file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096482/binding-container-managed-authentication-alias-with-datasource-using-jython-scri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call AppAdmin.install(path_to_ear) without options. Then options are read from the bnd file and there is no validation error. And ensure that `ibm-web-bnd.xml` file is in the ear file.

**UPDATE**

Ok I've noticed your error. In your binding file it should be the other way around:

```
<resource-ref name="jdbc/MyRef" binding-name="jdbc/JNDI" />
```

so in your case name is datasource2 and binding is jndiname - so datasource1:

```
<resource-ref binding-name="jdbc/dataSource1" name="jdbc/dataSource2"/>
```

Comment: I tried, i gave me the error i put in the question.
As for `ibm-web-bnd.xml` - in my application it located in war file inside an ear file. Am i doing it right? :)

Comment: It should be in WEB-INF folder, just beside your web.xml

Comment: @crew4ok you have error in binding file, see my updated answer.

Comment: damn, it seems to be working...
i'm sorry for asking such stupid questions and wasting your time guys...(
this file is a part of a legacy codebase, so i thought it should be okay.
anyway, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to add `MapResEnvRefToRes` option to `AdminApp.install` call to map resource reference to resource. Check this link for more:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rxml_taskoptions.html#rxml_taskoptions__cmd56

The quickest way to get it done is to enable "command assistance logging" and proceed with installation via AdminConsole. In the command assistance log you'll find the exact `AdminApp.install` syntax for your deployment and mapping of resource references to actual resources.

**Ad mode** *(I'm contributing to OSS project mentioned below)*

If you consider more sophisticated automation project (not just one application install), then you may find [WDR](http://wdr.github.io/WDR) library useful. With WDR you can export all your application settings into a manifest file, which includes `MapResEnvRefToRes` settings. Then you can deploy the application based on that manifest.

Comment: I considered Map* options as a workaround, since doesn't it seems to be a duplication of datasource definition? I defined it already in my web.xml and in ibm-web-bnd.xml files, can't WebSphere figure out the datasources mapping without me specifying it twice (i mean in ibm-web-bnd.xml AND in deployment script)?

Comment: btw, the library you mentioned seems really useful to me, but as i can get it consists of many files (which is opposite to a single file in wsadminlib.py, for instance) and i try to leave the deployment script as small as possible because it's supposed to be copied over ssh on many WS instances.